# can I plot 2 sets of data in the same density histogram (mathematica)?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, histogram2d

can I plot 2 different sets of data ({x1,y1} and also {x2,y2}) in the same density histogram (mathematica)?

I don't know if that is possible due to superposition of colors.

Comment: Have you looked at the function Show?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
a = SmoothDensityHistogram[
   RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[0.3], 10], Mesh -> 3, 
   MeshStyle -> Red, ColorFunction -> None];
b = SmoothDensityHistogram[
   RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[0.6], 10], Mesh -> 3, 
   MeshStyle -> Blue, ColorFunction -> None];
Show[
 a /. GrayLevel[_] -> Opacity[0],
 b /. GrayLevel[_] -> Opacity[0],
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]